# Service Cloud - Free developer edition - Where do I find?

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud

EDIT: I just start working with [trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/service_basics/service_basics_intro) but could not able to bring the `service console/dashboard` to follow the steps.

As shown below I have enabled/activate the service cloud in my profile. B where can I see `Service Cloud Console` in my free developer edition?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow below steps

1. Go to Setup -> Apps -> New

[image]

2. Select Console app type

[image]

3. Add tabs for console app.

[image]

4. Select Profile whom you want to make that visible

[image]

5. App will be available in app menu

[image]

Comment: In addition to @Himanshu 's answer. You can edit your profile and activate the default `Sample Console` app and Switch to that app from App menu/dropdown in your developer edition